# English translation of Dayananda Saraswati's commentary on RV X.85.45

Tags: rig-veda, marriage, translation-request, dayananda-saraswati

Commenting on the [wedding hymn](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10085.htm), RV X.85, verse 45, and probably trying to establish a Vedic basis for [niyoga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niyoga), Swami Dayananda Saraswati appears to have made some controversial remarks.

Is there an English translation of his commentary on RV X.85, especially, verse 45?

Here's how Ralph Griffith [translates](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10085.htm) that verse:

> RV_10,085.45a   imāṃ tvam indra mīḍhvaḥ suputrāṃ subhagāṃ kṛṇu | 
> RV_10,085.45c   daśāsyām putrān ā dhehi patim ekādaśaṃ kṛdhi ||
>
> 45   O Bounteous Indra, make this bride blest in her sons and fortunate. 
>       Vouchsafe to her ten sons, and make her husband the eleventh man.